# How to get started using tabris?

Tags: mobile

I want to use the tabris framework to develop cross platform mobile applications. What would be a good resource to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tutorial at http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/docs/create-a-hello-tabris/

It contains advice on how to setup a Tabris server, start a server-side helloworld example and access this example with the mobile clients on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

See an example at github - repository [Tabris Demos](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-demos).